# Send list email from list view on custom object

Tags: email, list-view

Is there a way to send a list email from a list view of a custom object?  @manjit5190 I am in Lightning list view.  When I am looking at Contacts list views, I have the List Email option.  Is there a way to have the List Email option when looking at list views on custom objects?

Comment: Michele, Are you in lex/community/classic/console?

Comment: @manjit5190 I am in Lightning list view.  When I am looking at Contacts list views, I have the List Email option.  Is there a way to have the List Email option when looking at list views on custom objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this at the moment. You can vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ViwQAE) which is asking for that functionality.

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_list_email_create.htm&type=5) mentions to make sure you have a **Contact** or **Lead** list view with the recipients you want (or a Campaign).

In the [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_list_email_considerations.htm&type=5) doc, it again mentions

> Before you send a list email—an email to a list of contacts, leads, or campaign members—consider a few key points.

[image]