# Send email list from custom object

Tags: lightning, email, workflow

So I have a custom Invoice object with a Invoice Reciever Email field.
I'm looking for a way to be able to select invoice objects from the List view and then send an email to each individual Invoice Reciever.
This proces is extremely similar to the Send Email List button within the Contacts object so I was wondering if the same feature can be used in a custom object.

Also, is it possible to integrate this into a custom flow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As we cannot do the mass email button on an custom objects standard list view, you might have to create an customized LWC component with a data-table and a button to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like have been asked already https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/299383/13583

Currently there is no possibility to do it. You can vote for this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ViwQAE) which is asking for that functionality.